# Confusion about flux linkage

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

When looking for a proper definition of flux linkage, I come across situations involving coils. with N turns, where it is $$N * flux per coil(p)$$ I understand that in this situation, the induced emf across the coil equals -d(N*p)/dt , hence it makes sense to discuss this 'flux linkage',which seems to capture the net effect of the field on induced EMF.However, I don't think  this definition is rigorous.Also, I wasn't able to explain the calculations used in other instances using similar logic.
I want to know how it is exactly defined.

Comment: What strikes you as non-rigorous about the definition? The only thing I can think of is when the flux linking different turns of the coil is different (as at the ends of a solenoid, where the flux density is less). In such cases we'd define the flux linkage as $$\text{flux linkage}=\sum_{r=1}^n \Phi_r$$ in which $\Phi_r$ is the flux passing through the $r$'th turn out of $n$ turns.

Answer (score 1):

If the same flux, $\Phi$, passes through each turn of a coil, the Faraday's-Lenz law can be written
$$\mathscr E=-N\frac{d\Phi}{dt}.$$
This can correctly be regarded as the sum of $N$ single turn emfs, $\mathscr E_1=-\frac{d\Phi}{dt}$, since these are in series.
Since $N$ is a constant we can clearly re-arrange our first equation as
$$\mathscr E=-\frac{d}{dt}\left(N\Phi \right).$$
and we can give the name 'flux linkage' to $N\Phi$.
Looked at this way, the concept of flux linkage seems to be more mathematically than physically inspired.

But there is a way of viewing the emf induced in a coil that doesn't use the idea of flux linkage, or at least doesn't distinguish it from flux. The idea is that the area, $A$, over which the normal flux density is of magnitude $B$ is not $A_1$, the area of a turn, but $NA_1$. This is because the coil is in fact not a collection of closed loops, but a helix, so there is really only one surface! From this point of view, even for a coil of $N$ turns, we can write simply
$$\mathscr E=-\frac{d\Phi}{dt}.$$
We must, though, remember that in this case $\Phi=BNA_1$.